# Which is correct? catch (_com_error e) or catch (_com_error& e)?

Tags: c++, exception, com

Which one should I use?

```
catch (_com_error e)
```

or

```
catch (_com_error& e)
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The second.  Here is my attempt at quoting Sutter

"Throw by value, catch by reference"

> Learn to `catch` properly: Throw exceptions by value (not pointer) and
>   catch them by reference (usually to `const`). This is the combination
>   that meshes best with exception semantics. When rethrowing the same
>   exception, prefer just `throw;` to `throw e;`.

Here's the full [Item 73. Throw by value, catch by reference.](http://www.informit.com/content/images/0321113586/items/sutter_item73.pdf)

---

The reason to avoid catching exceptions by value is that it implicitly makes a copy of the exception. If the exception is of a subclass, then information about it will be lost.

```
try { throw MyException ("error") } 
catch (Exception e) {
    /* Implies: Exception e (MyException ("error")) */
    /* e is an instance of Exception, but not MyException */
}
```

Catching by reference avoids this issue by not copying the exception.

```
try { throw MyException ("error") } 
catch (Exception& e) {
    /* Implies: Exception &e = MyException ("error"); */
    /* e is an instance of MyException */
}
```

Comment: Doug T: No the second. Catch by reference.

Comment: A bit more detail in the answer would be nice. Leave link for the exact details but put in details (and example) about the most accepted method.

Comment: Added some info and examples to the answer.

Comment: The exception is always copied. This is also important to note. Even if caught by reference. The difference is that you can downcast the reference to the subtype, while catch by value always slices the object.

Comment: Also, as stated in "C++ Coding Standards", you should use throw; to re-throw the execption if needed, not throw e; because the polymorphism is always preserved by throw; (but this is only useful if you catch by reference)

Answer (score 14):

Personally, I would go for the third option:

```
catch (const _com_error& e)
```

Comment: Yes, if at all possible, it should be const.

Answer (score 6):

Also, note that, when using MFC, you may have to [catch by pointer](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/exceptions.html#faq-17.8).  Otherwise, @JaredPar's answer is the way you should normally go (and hopefully never have to deal with things that throw a pointer).

Answer (score 3):

Definitely the second. If you had the following:

```
class my_exception : public exception
{
  int my_exception_data;
};

void foo()
{
  throw my_exception;
}

void bar()
{
  try
  {
    foo();
  }
  catch (exception e)
  {
    // e is "sliced off" - you lose the "my_exception-ness" of the exception object
  }
}
```

Comment: I believe the point of the question was whether to catch by reference or by value, not whether to catch some base class version of the exception.

Comment: The slicing problem is one of the main reasons you should always catch by reference

Comment: I see now what you mean - if e were caught by reference in your example, polymorphism would kick in appropriately.

Comment: Scott Meyers goes into great detail on this topic in Effective C++