# How do I catch and handle `_com_error`?

Tags: c++, exception, visual-c++, com

I currently have  code such as this

```
IAcctMaintPtr acct(__uuidof(AcctMaint));
acct->GetAccountList(q);
```

Now this code requires an external application to be running otherwise after the first statement I get an exception stating

> Unhandled exception at 0x7739c41f (KernelBase.dll) in myapp.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: _com_error at memory location 0x003ccefc..

I tried to `catch( const std::exception& )` but that doesn't seem to work - the exception is not being caught.

Any suggestion on how I could catch this exception ?

Comment: That did the trick. I was using catch(std::exception& e). Could u put that as an answer please

Comment: Note that you can switch to "check HRESULT" mode by simply using `raw_interfaces_only` with `#import` - saves you a ton of boilerplate code.

Comment: See also [Which is correct? catch (_com_error e) or catch (_com_error& e)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/151124/which-is-correct-catch-com-error-e-or-catch-com-error-e) about the `catch()` clause to use with `_com_error`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[_com_error](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0ye3k36s.aspx) does not derive from [std::exception](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/exception), but you can catch it explicitly:

```
try {
    IAcctMaintPtr acct(__uuidof(AcctMaint));
    acct->GetAccountList(q);
} catch (_com_error& x) {
    // Handle error in 'x'...
}
```